# How to Add Global/Public Variables to grunt-contrib-uglify Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-uglify

Okay, so I am way new to Grunt and Node.js. I am building a site, and decided that the 'main.js' file was getting way too big. So, I split it up, and I am now trying to use Grunt to piece all of these JS files back together.

The issue that I have is that I need to make some global variables available to all of the various functions in all of these JS files. To be more specific, every page on our site is identified via an `id` in the body tag:

```
<body id="home">
```

Many of these JS files contain if statements that ensure certain functions only run if the appropriate page is loaded. For example:

```
if (page == 'home') {
    var title = "Home Page"
    $('.page-title').text(title);
}
```

Notice the `page` variable? That guy is the one that I need to make available to all of these files (after grunt-contrib-uglify merges them together). So, I figured I'd assign a new "unique" variable name, and make it global.

I noticed that [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) has a '[wrap](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#wrap)' option listed in its documentation. However, no examples are given as to how to use it.

Can anyone tell me:
- How to use the 'wrap' option in 'grunt-contrib-uglify'
- If this is the right grunt plugin for what I am trying to do?

One idea I had (as a last resort) is to create a `before.js` and `after.js` and put the beginning and end (respectively) of what I wish to wrap around the other files in each. But, I think the 'wrap' option is what I need, yes?

***UPDATE:*** Here is a link to my "merged" JS file:
[main.js](http://nwca.com/js/main.js)

And a link to my Gruntfile:
[Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/DerekFoulk/nwca-nitrosell/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

Comment: So, let me try to clear that up, you have files like file1.html file2.html, and they all import your (after minifying) _main.min.js_? And you need your variable `page` available in some inline javascript inside your html files?

Comment: Negative, I have a series of JS files that are "merged" using **grunt-contrib-concat**. Each one of these files is wrapped in it's own `$(document).ready(function(){});` and (in some cases) other events like `$(window).load(function(){});` and `$(window).resize(function(){});`. So, I needed to (at the very beginning of the merged file) have `page = $(body).attr('id');`, and at the very end of the "merged" file, a series of functions that are used in all of these various files. So something at the very beginning, and something at the end. So, is the '**wrap**' option what I should use?

Comment: I accomplished the behaviour I wanted via `src: ['src/js/banner.js', 'src/js/*.js', 'src/js/functions.js']` where **banner.js** holds my `page = $('body').attr('id');` and **functions.js** holds the series of functions. But, I am still unsure the intended use of the '**wrap**' option of **grunt-contrib-uglify**. Does it do the same thing? If so, how (and with what syntax)?

Comment: I added a link to my OP that shows the produced JS file...

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem an searching for a solution. But I think I found an answer.

Use this in your gruntfile:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    wrap: true
  }
}
```

The documentation for the `wrap` property indicates that the variables will be made available in a global variable, and looking at the generated code that does seem to to be the case. Passing a string value to the parameter does seem to create a global variable with that name.

However, `wrap: true` seems to make all objects and properties available in the global scope. So instead of `globals.page.title` (which I can't get to work, anyway), you can just use `page.title`. Much, much easier and simpler.

If this suits your purposes, I'd recommend doing this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one is tricky, I have been stucked for a while...

Way you do this with **grunt-contrib-uglify** for **frontend JS**

create multiple files like

```
SomeClass.js
OtherClass.js
main.js
```

and use some module (grunt-file-dependencies or grunt-contrib-concat) and setup it to concat your files. Then setup uglify in your `Gruntfile.js` like

```
...
uglify: {
    options: {
        wrap: "myPublicObject",
        ...
    },
```

In file (`main.js` for example) `exports` variable has to be assigned, the entire file might look like this:

```
var otherClassInst = new OtherClass();
var someClassInst = new SomeClass();

exports = otherClassInst;
```

**Now what it exactly does**

Uglify will pick superior context (`this`) and define property on it named `myPublicObject`. Then it wrap your sourcecode with function and create exports variable here (**DO NOT DECLARE** `var exports` **anywhere**). At the end it will assign what you exported to that property. If you dont assign anything (you dont use exports =) inital value is `{}`, so the property with void object exists anyway.

To make this super-clear,

1. if you put your code into page like `<script src="myminifiedfile.min.js"></script>`, then superior context is `window` =>
   `window.myPublicObject` is instance of `OtherClass` while `window.someClassInst`, `window.SomeClass` and `window.OtherClass` are `undefined`.
2. this is unlikely, but if you just copy content of minified result and wrap it with different function, object you exported will be visible only via `this["myPublicObject"]` => uglify wrap doesn't make things globaly accessible, it makes them accessible in superior context.